# Check content of attributes using rspec+webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, rspec, webrat

With rspec+webrat you can check various attributes like `:href`, `:content`, `:class` etc but how can I check the content of html5 custom attributes. It seems to complain about the second part of the attribute name.

If attribute is `'data-random'` and I try to use `have_selector('li', :data-random => 'string')` it will complain that `random` is an `undefined local variable or method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has more to do with the syntax of Ruby symbols. They cannot contain hyphen characters, unless they are quoted. Try this instead:

```
have_selector('li', :'data-random' => 'string')
```

Comment: It didn't seem to like that either.

Comment: Oops! Just tried using this again `:'data-method' => "delete"` and it worked.

Comment: How can i check the display:block in rspec+webrat?